# Finding the Fourier series of a piecewise function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm s little confused about Fourier series of functions that are piecewise. Here’s an example of such a function:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x & -\frac\pi2 < x < \frac\pi2 \\[5pt]
\pi - x & \frac\pi2 < x < \frac{3\pi}2
\end{cases}$$
Please can you explain this example to me?

Comment: There is a standard formula to compute coefficients $a_0, a_n, b_n$. Your question is how these coefficients are derived or how they get computed?

Comment: yes,in other word in don't know the interval of integral for obtaining coefficients.

Comment: Remember that you're not computing coefficients for two different functions - you're computing the coefficients of one function, except you will have two integrals when computing the Fourier coefficients due to the function being piecewise across the period.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your function is defined on the interval $\left(-\dfrac \pi 2,  \dfrac \pi 2 \right)\cup \left( \dfrac \pi 2 , \dfrac {3\pi} 2\right) $. That means the length of the interval is $\boxed{L= 2\pi}$.

Now, how to compute the coefficients:

$a_0=\displaystyle \dfrac 1 L \cdot\int_{-\frac \pi 2}^ \frac {3\pi} 2 f(x) \, dx=\dfrac 1 L\cdot \bigg(\int_{-\frac \pi 2}^ \frac {\pi} 2 x \, dx +\int_{\frac \pi 2}^ \frac {3\pi} {2} (\pi- x)  \, dx\bigg)$

$a_n=\displaystyle \dfrac 2 L \cdot\int_{-\frac \pi 2}^ \frac {3\pi} 2 f(x)\cdot \cos\left(\dfrac {2n\pi x} {L}\right) \, dx$

$b_n=\displaystyle \dfrac 2 L \cdot\int_{-\frac \pi 2}^ \frac {3\pi} 2 f(x)\cdot \sin\left(\dfrac {2n\pi x} {L}\right) \, dx$

The Fourier series of $f$ is:

$$ \displaystyle a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big[a_n\cdot \cos\left(\dfrac {2n\pi x} {L}\right)+b_n \cdot \sin\left(\dfrac {2n\pi x} {L}\right)\Big]$$

Comment: but we know for obtaining coefficients we have to integrate function from [-T/2,T/2] and intervals are Symmetric but you didn't write that.I have been confused now.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary to be always true. 

In general, $a_n=\displaystyle\int_{x_0}^{x_0+L} f(x)\cdot \cos\bigg(\dfrac { 2 n \pi x } {L}\bigg)\, dx$ , where $L$ stands for the period of the periodic function.